# Placing words between the preposition and object, like "by not only this" vs "not only by this"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Is there any change in meaning if you put some words before the preposition or place them between the preposition and object?

- 1: *You can reach the place **not only by** walking but also by a bus.* vs
- 2: *You can reach the place **by not only** walking but also by a bus.*

or

- 3: *You can write **not only with** a pencil but also with a pen.* vs
- 4: *You can write **with not only** a pencil but also with a pen.*

Comment: (3) and (4) should use _with_, not _by_. Instruments use _with_, agents use _by_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *not only A but also B*

is a fixed structure, where A and B are the same parts of speech. The sentences 2 and 4 smash the structure and are, therefore, incorrect.

In the sentences 1 and 3, *by walking* (A) and *by a bus* (B) resp. *by a pencil* (A) and *by a pen* (B) are all adverbial expressions (how? by which means?).

In the sentences 2 and 4, *walking* (A) resp. *a pencil* (A) are no adverbial expressions and don't match with their respective B, which is still an adverbial expression.

I you removed the second *by* from the sentences 2 and 4 they would be grammatically correct again, because neither A's nor B' would be adverbial expressions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to which sentences in my question you refer, so I marked them 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @Jan I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, it is. Still, I'm utterly confused by this, because I see a LOT of this online. I narrowed the online search to: "[not by only giving](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=918&ei=dblXXsKiDfGR1fAPlIG14A0&q=%22not+by+only+giving%22&oq=%22not+by+only+giving%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.37701.39245..39869...1.0..0.102.719.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i8i30j0i8i10i30j33i160j0i8i7i30j0i8i7i10i30.zkLf7W73XJQ&ved=0ahUKEwiCsfOM4fHnAhXxSBUIHZRADdwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)" (in quotes) and I got 14.500 results.

Comment: OK; I get it. So, it's just about removing "by" before "B" in 2 and 4.

Comment: @Jan The results you get are no _not only ... but also_ structures as you presented them in the question. There, _only_ doesn't belong to _not_. It belongs to the following word and describes it.